# Feature Standardize in AutoML H2O

Tags: r, h2o, h2o.ai

I'm wondering how to standardize features when using `h2o`'s `AutoML` with deep learning and GLM algorithms.

Seems it is supported to deep learning and GLM models (https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/standardize.html), but in `h2o.automl` it does not accept the `standardize = TRUE` argument.

My questions are:

1. Does autoML automatically scales (i.e. standardizes) the features when deeplearning or GLM algorithm is used?

If true, does it automatically standardize also when I predict on new test data?

2. If 1) is not true, is there a built-in `h2o` function that achieves this so that I can do it manually? What's the recommended workflow for this with `AutoML`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, H2O AutoML uses most of the hyperparameter defaults in GLM and Deep Learning, and both of those default to `standardize = TRUE`.
2. In H2O, every transformation that happens in training will happen at predict time, so you don't need to worry.

Comment: @LeDell Thank you very much. Does standardize = TRUE in Deep Learning, GLM, ..., standardize the target variable altogether, or only features?

Comment: Linking your answered question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76131318/h2o-variable-standardization