# H2O Variable standardization

Tags: machine-learning, h2o

The documentation in standardize section https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/standardize.html only includes these algorithms: Deep Learning, GLM, GAM, K-Means.

I have two questions:

1. Does it mean that other algorithms such as Random Forest, Gradient Boosting, etc, are not standardizing (at least automatically in AutoML)?
2. Does `standardize = TRUE` in Deep Learning, GLM, ..., standardize the target variable altogether, or only features?

A related question is [Feature Standardize in AutoML H2O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73804485/feature-standardize-in-automl-h2o).

Comment: Tree-based algorithms (RF, gradient boosting etc) do not require standardization; see own answer in [Is it necessary to normalize data for XGBoost?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/60950/is-it-necessary-to-normalize-data-for-xgboost/60954#60954) in Data Science SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your question 1.  Correct.  For algorithms that do not have the standardize parameter, the predictors are not standardized.  For tree based algorithms, we are dealing with comparisons like val >= threshold to determine which side of the child nodes to go to.  If we implement standardization, we will have to perform (val-mean)/standard deviation >= threshold.  In choosing not to standardize will say us a lot of time during the tree traversal because we don't need to perform standardization of the predictors when we are trying to evaluate the expression val >= threshold.

Regarding question 2: When you set standardize=true, only the numerical features are standardized.  The response column is not standardized.

Comment: Any corroboration for answer #2?